# SSH/OpenMPI: Permission Denied with mpirun but fine with ssh

Tags: ssh, mpi

I am trying to setup a cluster of four nodes (all running Fedora 22) with OpenMPI.

On the master node, I've created a password-less key (~/.ssh/id_dsa) and copied ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub to each of the three slave nodes' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.  So, from the master node, I can run `ssh slave1`, `ssh slave2`, or `ssh slave3` and successfully get into the corresponding node, without being asked for a password.  Same goes for `ssh master`.

However, I run into permission problems when I try to use `mpirun`.  Here is the command I run:

```
/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpirun -np 32 --hostfile .mpi_hostfile ./testprogram
```

and here is the first bit of the output:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
```

When I subsequently run `ssh slave3`, I see the message "There were 2 failed login attempts since the last successful login."  So it looks like the ssh authentication that `mpirun` is trying to do is failing for some reason.

Any ideas why I can do my password-less, key-based authentication just fine with `ssh`, but not with `mpirun`?

For the record, here is the contents of `.mpi_hostfile`:

```
# Host file for OpenMPI

# Master node, slots = num cores
localhost slots=8

# Slaves
slave1 slots=8
slave2 slots=8
slave3 slots=8
```

Comment: Try running sshd with debugging enabled on one of the slave nodes. You can do this by adding a line `LogLevel DEBUG3` to its `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and restarting the daemon. The log entries will show up in syslog. If they are not enlightening, post them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because Open MPI defaults to using a tree-based launching scheme.  E.g., ssh from the machine where you invoke mpirun to slave1, and then ssh from slave1 to slave2, ...etc.

See http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi and http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/tree-based-launch-in-open-mpi-part-2 for more details.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, this was exactly the info needed to debug this problem.  One of the slaves didn't have the ssh key of another slave in authorized_keys, so that one link didn't work.  Those two articles are a great resource and explain the issue I was having.

Comment: Cool.  Please upvote the answer so that others know that this was the correct solution.  Thanks!